# How to check each object in array in ReactJS + Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

I have an object array of users, which each object has 'username' and 'password'.

There is then a login page, where once the user enters in a username and a password, I want to pass that into the reducer and compare them with each object in the 'users' array, and if an object that matches both, 'password' and 'username', is found, I want it return 'true'.

Following is the reducer:

```
const usersReducer = function(users = [], action){
  switch (action.type){

    case 'VERIFY_USER':
        return users.map((user)=> {
          if(user.username === action.username && user.password ===  action.password){
            return true
          } else{
          return false
          }
        })
      }

    default:
      return users
  }
}
```

But it seems to return true all the time. Am I using map correct? If not, is there such a method where it'll go through each object in an array? Any insight or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

EDIT**
Calling it from the following:

```
  verifyLoginUser(){
    event.preventDefault()

    if(this.props.actions.verifyUser(this.props.loginUser.username, this.props.loginUser.password)){
      console.log('LOGGED IN')
    } else {
      console.log('NOT LOGGED IN')
    }
  }
```

With the following reducer:

```
case 'VERIFY_USER':
  let isVerified = false;
  users.forEach((user)=> {
    if(user.username === action.username && user.password ===  action.password){
      isVerified = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return isVerified;
```

Comment: [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: hopefully this is just something you're making for fun and not actually releasing, as storing+checking the passwords the way you're doing it is about as insecure as you can get

Comment: @Hamms not hooked up to a safe backend yet. this is just for testing and learning. appreciate the concern!

Comment: @Hamms could you provide an example?

Comment: `return users.find(user => user.username === action.username && user.password ===  action.password)`

Comment: You may not want a reducer. The purpose of a reducer should be to update the store. This seems more like a utility that takes a username/password and tells you if it matches something in the store.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson I'm still learning ReactJS at the moment. Could you please show the right practice to implement it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.some](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
return users.some(user => user.username === action.username && user.password === action.password);
```

Comment: they want to actually retrieve the relevant user

Comment: @Hamms He/she said `I want it return 'true'.`, so this will be fine for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Map function would return you an array. I suggest using a different native array function: 'find'. To check if user object exists in the array of users, you can do

```
function findUser(user) { 
    return (user.username === action.username && user.password === action.password);
}

var isUser = users.find(findUser) ? true : false;
return isUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean variable and forEach to accomplish what you want

```
case 'VERIFY_USER':
    let isVerified = false;
    users.forEach((user)=> {
        if(user.username === action.username && user.password ===  action.password){
            isVerified = true;
            return false;
        } 
    });
    return isVerified;
```

to take this a step further lets say you wanted to iterate on this and return the correct user so that way you can populate a currentUser with it or something.

```
case 'VERIFY_USER':
    let currentUser = null;
    users.forEach((user)=> {
        if(user.username === action.username && user.password ===  action.password){
            currentUser = user;
            return false;
        } 
    });
    return currentUser;
```

## EDIT: to what we were talking about in the comments

lets say you make a request to login a user somewhere. and the function lives on your props

```
this.props.loginUser({my params here});
```

**now your actual action.**

```
loginUser = (data) => {
    // whatever method you are using to make the request goes here.
    someRequestMethod('/login/, data).then( (response) => {
        if(response.status === 200){
            dispatch(type: USER_LOGIN, payload: response.data); // whatever the user is that comes back from the response. I just put data for an example
        }
    })
}
```

**now in your reducer**

```
const populateState = (user) => {
    return {
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        isAuthenticated: Object.keys(user).length > 0
    };
}
let defaultState = {id: null, username: '', email: '', isAuthenticated: false};
const loginReducer = (currentUser = defaultState) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'USER_LOGIN':
            return Object.assign({}, currentUser, populateState(action.payload));
    return currentUser;
}
```

**finally, everywhere else you just look for the current user.**

```
if(this.props.currentUser.isAuthenticated){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry but why is it returning false inside the if-statement.

Comment: @JoKo the return false is just to break the forEach loop. you are returning (to redux) isVerified which is set to true when you have a correct value. (the forEach defaults to returning true so that the next iteration of the for loop will happen. i'm breaking out of that loop because we already found the correct person).

Comment: Appreciate the clarification but still don't seem to work as intended. Is it possible to open up a chat? Would really appreciate it. Been stuck on this since yesterday..

Comment: Try printing out the user in each iteration of the forEach

Comment: @JoKo also try printing out the action.username and password too.. I assume it may be a lowercase uppercase issue or something. where your comparison is not working properly

Comment: I did quadruple check but can't seem to find the problem. I added new code in the original post. It's alway logging 'LOGGED IN' no matter what has been entered in the username and password input, when it should log 'NOT LOGGED IN' when the 'users' array is empty.

Comment: You are using the logic of logged in incorrectly. you should instead on login set a current user variable that stores the current user. so something like. when the user hits login dispatch LOGIN_SUCCESS with the user information. then you can just say if(this.props.currentUser)... meaning you have a valid session

Comment: I tried but still no luck... Do you mind showing a snippet of what you are describing? Appreciate it John.

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous message. Let me know.

Comment: Yep sorry I've been super busy, when the login happens you have a callback function for the success right? Dispatch from there and pass that user or whatever you want to store. From there you should have access to that value assuming it's captured by your reducer and you are mapping state to props

Comment: I am not sure if I am thinking of the same callback function. Could you show? Still in the learning process so want to do so the right way

Comment: @JoKo ok edited take a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for making the attempt to help! I am trying to understand at the moment and have a few questions if you don't mind. Sorry I am still a beginner. What would go in {my params here}? And by 'this.props.loginUser', are you referring to the same one as in the original post? And what is '/login/ in someRequestMethod and what does someRequestMethod represent in relation to my code? Thanks John!

Comment: Checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know. Thank you John!